# How do I capture the first character typed in a cell of a DataGridView with EditMode.EditProgrammatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have set

```
EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
```

on my DataGridView because I do not want repeated single clicks to start edit mode. (This happens with all other EditMode settings).

Now I have overridden OnKeyDown and called BeginEdit to start editing the cells when the user is typing.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  BeginEdit(true);
  base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

The problem is that the event handling seems to swallow the first keypress or maybe BeginEdit is called too late.

Here is some code that can be pasted into a new VS C# project that demonstrates the problem.
(Just replace the generated Form1 definition when pasting.)

```
  public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
  {
    public MyDataGridView()
    {
      this.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      BeginEdit(true);
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
  }

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;

    public Form1()
    {
      this.dataGridView1 = new MyDataGridView();
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
      this.SuspendLayout();

      this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
      this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
      this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

      this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);

      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
      this.ResumeLayout(false);


      this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", "foo");
      this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", "bar");
      this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try overriding the OnKeyPress event instead and send the key that was pressed:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (!IsCurrentCellInEditMode) {
    BeginEdit(true);
    SendKeys.Send(e.KeyChar.ToString());
  }
  base.OnKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you very much! (It is really hard to figure this kind of stuff out it seems.)